# Why is ordered choice in pyparsing failing for my use case?

Tags: python, pyparsing

```
>>> g = MatchFirst( Literal("scoobydoo"), Literal("scooby") )
>>> g.parseString( "scooby" )
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "scoobydoo" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Is the ParseException thrown because the `scooby` has already been consumed in the character stream & thus the parser cannot backtrack ? I'm looking for a detailed implementation explanation for this.

At the moment, I consider this a bug because why would the parser short-circuit the matching since it has not search all the choices in production rule.

***UPDATE***:

*Seems like `MatchFirst` is not exactly equivalent to `|` operator. Why ?*

```
>>> g = Literal("scoobydoo") | Literal("scooby")
>>> g.parseString("scooby").asList()
['scooby']
>>> g.parseString("scoobydoo").asList()
['scoobydoo']
```

Comment: I don't understand your update - why do you think '|' and MatchFirst are different?  '|' generates MatchFirst instances, and '^' generates Or instances.  If you reorder your definition of `g` to look for "scooby" first, you will never match "scoobydoo". If you leave the order the same, but change '|' to '^', then things will work again.

Comment: Although both `|` and `MatchFirst` are equivalent; my updated snippet shows that parsing `scooby` does **not** cause a `ParseException`, whereas it did in my original snippet.

Comment: Ah! You wrote `MatchFirst(Literal("scoobydoo"),Literal("scooby"))` - what you should write is `MatchFirst([Literal("scoobydoo"),Literal("scooby")])`.  MatchFirst expects up to 2 args, the first is a list of expressions, the second is a boolean flag on whether to save the data as a list or as a string. Without enclosing the 2 Literals in a list, you are building a MatchFirst using just `Literal("scoobydoo")`, which as you observed, does not match "scooby".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatchFirst` (or '|') does short-circuiting by design.  To force all alternatives to be checked, use `Or` (or '^').  `oneOf("scooby scoobydoo")` will also work, since `oneOf` will short-circuit, but only after rearranging alternative words that have leading overlaps.

Comment: Yes. I have a personal bias for MatchFirst over Or, so I made the effort to keep the API simple, but under the covers ensure that match testing is done to select the longest matching given alternative, without necessarily having to evaluate all possible alternatives.